# System f-sub, how to do type checking?

Tags: type-theory, type-checking, type-inference

I was reading that system f-sub (polymorphic lambda calculus with sub-typing) and I was quite confused with its one checking rule called "T-TAPP".

This rule as following (ctx denotes the typing context)

```
   ctx |- t1 : ∀X<:T11. T12    ,    ctx |- T2<:T11
   -----------------------------------------------
            ctx |- t1 [T2] : [X-->T2]T12
```

I could not understand how '[x-->T2]T12' will be used (I know it is substitution). This rule appears on page 10 in the following source.
I am looking for two type checking examples, in which above inference rule will be applied and at least one example is a case of type checking failure.

Could anyone provide me with concrete examples?
[Description of system F-sub](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~plclub/poplmark/poplmark.pdf)

Comment: "J.B.Wells, Typability and type checking in System F are equivalent and undecidable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is old but the previous answer has a huge misconception.

The following function is in System F.

$f = \lambda X. X \rightarrow X \rightarrow X$

All we know of this function is it selects one of its arguments and can be instantieded with any type; $\ f$ [**Bool**] : **Bool** $\rightarrow$ **Bool** $\rightarrow$ **Bool**.

In System $F_{<:}$ is possible to have the following function.

$f' = \lambda X<:$**Number**$.\ X \rightarrow X \rightarrow X$

This function can be the addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, etc, and can be instantiated with subtypes of **Number**.

$f'$ [**Int**], $\ f'$ [**Double**], $\ f'$ [**Real**] are valid instantiations, but $\ f'$ [**Bool**] not, because **Bool** is not a subtype of **Nat**.

Dependent types are a different thing. It has nothing to do here and is out of the scope of the question, but it is a very interesting topic. See [Lambda Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is about subtypes, not about Dependent types.

Comment: And also answer the question. It should be the accepted answer for future people with the same doubts

Answer (score 1):

It would've helped if you mentioned what page that rule appears in.

Anyhow, from what I can tell here's an example.

```
⊢ t₁ : ∀ X <: Animal. “X makes noise”            ⊢ Cat <: Animal
------------------------------------------------------------
                     ⊢  t₁ [Cat] : “Cat makes noise”
```

The **idea** seems to be that t₁ is to be treated as a generic function, or a dependently-typed function, in that for each Animal subtype X, in our example, it gives us a proof t₁[X] and the rule just formalises this idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was expecting a type checking example in this system, such as to prove  "ctx |- t : T". so rules applies from bottom-up fashion. I could not figure out how to apply that rule in such cases.